# what layout should I use to achieve desired looking?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the search view stay left and when user click on it will expand. also I want an icon float right. 
if I use relative layout, it works fine until the search view expands.

[image: relative layout]
[image: relative layout]
if I use liner layout and give them weight the icon will always stay next to search view.

[image: linear layout]
[image: linera layout]what should I do?

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    ></SearchView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/setting"/>

</LinearLayout>

< RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></SearchView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/setting"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the XML layouts that you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried setting a width to your `SearchView`?

Answer (score 2):

If using a relative layout, you just have to tell the search view to stay left of the icon and have the settings icon line up right in the parent.  Here is a working example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.example.myapplication.EllipsizeActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv_icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like collapsed:

[image: collapsed]

and expanded:

[image: expanded]